# Wake on LAN - Does the IP address have to be correct?

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan

My understanding of WOL is that it broadcasts a magic-packet into a subnet. The packet goes to all NICs and each inspects the packet for their own MAC and on a match, wakes the host.

So, could I put the IP address and subnet mask of the local machine from which I'm sending the packet, running the command, and a MAC of another host on my subnet and it will broadcast locally and wake the node?

I'm not on site, so I can't try it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your remote host is located on the same physical network you do not have to worry about its IP configuration, there is no need for that.

Comment: Tested and confirmed using Depicus .exe sending to remote MAC but using sender's machine's IP add and subnet, port 7.